# Add a field to a field list using case satement mysql

Tags: mysql, syntax

I am trying to use a case statement to populate a field (status) that is not in a table that I am selecting from is this possible

```
SELECT j.JobID, j.Company, j.WellName,j.RigNumber,
CASE 
WHEN j.JobComplete = 1 Then status = 'Job Complete'
WHEN j.JobInitiated = 1 Then status = 'Job Initiated'
WHEN j.JobInProgress = 1 Then status = 'In Initiated'
WHEN j.JobPotential = 1 Then status = 'Job Potential' 
WHEN j.JobCancelled = 1 Then status = 'Job Cancelled'
WHEN j.JobInvoiced = 1 Then status = 'Job Invoiced'
WHEN j.JobPaid = 1 Then status = 'Job Paid'
END AS 'status',

jdn.NotesTime,jdn.Username,jdn.Notes
FROM Job as j
JOIN JobDailyNotes as jdn ON jdn.jobid = j.jobid
WHERE jdn.NotesTime Between '1900-01-01 12:00:00' AND '2014-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work, but the answer will be based on the first "WHEN" clause that qualifies.  Based on your query, if a job was completed, but not paid, the status would still be "Job Complete"

```
CASE 
WHEN j.JobComplete = 1 Then status = 'Job Complete'
WHEN j.JobInitiated = 1 Then status = 'Job Initiated'
WHEN j.JobInProgress = 1 Then status = 'In Initiated'
WHEN j.JobPotential = 1 Then status = 'Job Potential' 
WHEN j.JobCancelled = 1 Then status = 'Job Cancelled'
WHEN j.JobInvoiced = 1 Then status = 'Job Invoiced'
WHEN j.JobPaid = 1 Then status = 'Job Paid'
end Status...
```

So, you may need to adjust it to better qualify what you are looking for as a single status column with the "final" step as paid-in-full might be your FIRST when clause, then working back from that such as:

```
CASE 
WHEN j.JobPaid = 1 Then status = 'Job Paid'
WHEN j.JobComplete = 1 Then status = 'Job Complete'
WHEN j.JobInvoiced = 1 Then status = 'Job Invoiced'
WHEN j.JobCancelled = 1 Then status = 'Job Cancelled'
WHEN j.JobInProgress = 1 Then status = 'In Initiated'
WHEN j.JobInitiated = 1 Then status = 'Job Initiated'
WHEN j.JobPotential = 1 Then status = 'Job Potential' 
end Status...
```